# Image distorted on different resolution devices when using scaleType="fitXY"

Tags: android, imageview, scaletype

I have a carousel banner and I have the requirement the images to cover all the layout and be displayed the same irrespective of device resolution. Below is the original image, device screenshot of correct use and lastly, device screenshot of wrong use

[image: original image]

[image: correct]

[image: wrong]

As you can see in the last image, the circle on the right upper part of the image becomes oval shaped, which is not the case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#232323">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/advert_carousel_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Image is set using Glide

```
Glide
    .with(mContext)
    .load(img)
    .into(advertCarouselBackground);
```

Any ideas on how the original image can be displayed without distortion independently of device resolution? I have tried some solutions, like converting the image to bitmap, setting width and height programmatically, calculating aspect ratio, etc, but nothing worked so far.

Comment: Well, what do you want to happen if the device's aspect ratio doesn't match the aspect ratio of your image? `scaleType="fitXY"` means that the image can be scaled along the X and Y axes independenly (i.e. the image's aspect ratio doesn't need to be maintained).

Comment: I have understood that. But I have the requirement that the image covers all the area (that is why I used fitXY) and also does not get distorted at all. I don't see how this can happen. I' ve also tried with layout_constraintDimensionRatio, but it don't work properly as well

Comment: Yeah that doesn't really sound doable. What you could try since you're using `ConstraintLayout` is to change the `layout_width` and `layout_height` for the `ImageView` to `"0dp"`, and add `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"` (or whatever the image's aspect ratio is). But you'll get some empty space around the image if the screen has a different aspect ratio.

Comment: change the scaleType, add these two lines in your Layout's XML 
 android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

OR 

you can do it through Glide image resize feature.

Glide.with(context)
.load(path)
.apply(new RequestOptions().override(600, 200))
.into(imageViewResizeCenterCrop);